# Regex to match word in a URL

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression which matches:

```
http://example.com/foo
http://example.com/foo/
http://example.com/foo/bar
```

but not:

```
http://example.com/foobar
```

Using `http://example.com/foo/?` matches the three types, but it matches `/foobar` too that I don't want. What should I add to the regex to not match `/foobar`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

```
^http://example\.com/foo(?:/.*)?$
```

Comment: Marking this as an answer. FlopCoder's solution works too, but I like this one better. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In your regex, the last `/?` means an optional `/` at the end. So `/foobar` is also matched.
Try this:

```
http:\/\/example\.com\/foo($|\/.*)
```

Comment: http:\/\/example\.com\/foo\/.* might be a better fit.

Comment: Argh. Leaning slash syndrome!

Comment: @synthesizerpatel: why do you want to escape the `/` ?

Comment: If you used the regex in say, a search/replace - the unescape slashes would mess it up. Always be in the habit of escaping special characters.

Comment: @synthesizerpatel: slash is not a special character unless you use it as regex delimiter.

Comment: There's no penalty for backslashing a forward slash, it doesn't change the behavior. But, to each their own. I like my regex's cut-and-pastable into vi, source code or shell. Some people may not.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
http://example.com/foo(?:\/|/(\w+)|)
```

In regex form:

```
/http:\/\/example.com\/foo(?:\/|\/(\w+)|)/
```

This will match example.com/foo or example.com/foo/bar or example.com/foo/

---

Some explaination:

- `(foo|bar)` matches foo or bar
- `(?:)` a group with the `?:` in the begin will not been captured
- `\/` will match a / at the end
- `\/(\w+)` match a / with a word character who is repeated one or more times
- `|)` will match nothing at the end of the string.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but couldn't get this to work. It still matched /foobar. FlopCoder's solution works. Thank anyway for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a negative lookahead (`?!`) for this:

```
$urls = array(
    'http://example.com/foo',
    'http://example.com/foo/',
    'http://example.com/foo/bar',
    'http://example.com/foobar'
);

foreach ($urls as $url) {
    if (preg_match('#^http://example\.com/foo(?!bar)#', $url)) {
        echo $url, " matches.\n";
    } else {
        echo $url, " does NOT match.\n";
    }
}

// Output:
// http://example.com/foo matches.
// http://example.com/foo/ matches.
// http://example.com/foo/bar matches.
// http://example.com/foobar does NOT match.
```

Comment: I think in general he doesn't want to match `/foobar`, `/food`, `/foo-fighters`. You don't know ahead of time what you want to avoid matching.

Comment: Exactly, /foobar was just an example.

Comment: @Tenner: Ah, okay, my mistake.  I took it to mean that he was just trying not to match one particular bit of text ("bar") if it didn't have a preceding slash.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript Regular Expression

https?://(example.com)/?/[^/]*/?(bar)?

Test here:(More Info..)

http://tools.netshiftmedia.com/regexlibrary/